# get mysql data between two dates using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am Trying to fetch Data between two dates, date was stored as `DATETIME` in mysql and showing as `2016-04-02 04:55:03`

to get dates I am using bootstrap datetimepicker with input form like below

```
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkin" name="from_date" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" placeholder="Select Start Date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
   </div>
   <div class="gap-small"></div>
   <div class="input-group date">
       <input type="text" class="form-control datechange" id="checkout" name="to_date" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" placeholder="Select End Date">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
   </div>
```

and i am using AJAX to send these values to PHP.

in result page:

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

result:

```
    array(3) { ["from_date"]=> string(10) "30/03/2016" ["to_date"]=> string(10) "05/04/2016" ["search_place"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } }
```

i am getting values in `from_date` and `to_date`

now when i am trying to retrive between from and to dates its not working below is my sql statement

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE evedate BETWEEN '" . $from_date . "' AND  '" . $to_date . "'";
```

Comment: you have a closing bracket in your query that is never opened?
What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: DATETIME format  2016-04-02 but you get data as 30/03/2016

Comment: yes not getting date as 30/03/2016

Comment: I think channasmcs has answered your question, you need to convert 30/03/2016 to 2016-03-30 for the SQL query to work

Comment: tyied strtodate but not woring

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE evedate BETWEEN concat(str_to_date('".from_date."','%d/%m/%Y'),' 00:00:00') AND concat(str_to_date('".to_date."','%d/%m/%Y'),' 23:59:59')` is the proper solution, I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE evedate BETWEEN concat(str_to_date('".$from_date."','%d/%m/%Y')) AND concat(str_to_date('".$to_date."','%d/%m/%Y')
```

is working

Comment: any better answer ? please share

Comment: @AseshaGeorge, if `evedate` is in datetime format, you must concat `$from_date` with `00:00:00` and `$to_date` with `23:59:59`, otherwhise the query will cut some to_date dates. see my comment above, you had it as suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date DATE_FORMAT

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATE_FORMAT(evedate, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '" . $from_date . "' AND  '" . $to_date . "'";
```